# ASP.NET MVC, Node.JS. Can they interact?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, node.js

Can `ASP.NET MVC` application somehow interact (*for example synchronize account data*) with websites written on top of `NODE.JS` and hosted on some of 'node-clouds'?

Comment: Em, you fire one application on one port and the other on another. And they can communicate. I'm not sure what's the question.

Comment: @Sohhee, @freakish I know about Microsoft porting the Node.js. But I'm interested in interaction with `Node.js application` on its native  (*nix) platform.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. You fire Node.JS app as a stand-alone server on one machine and you fire your ASP.NET server on second machine ( they do not have to be physically different ). Then you can communicate between those two servers via REST. It's basically the same as communication between browser and the server.

Comment: Ok I understand), please write your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general problem. If you have two applications written in two different languages or running on two different machines or whatever the reason is that makes them separate they can still communicate.

You fire one server on one machine and the other on another. Servers are meant to serve things, so their main functionality is to listen on a port and respond to incoming requests. But they are not limited to this. They can fire requests as well! There is no reason why server can't be a client at the same time.

Basically what you need to do is to add client functionality to the server, so it can make requests to other servers. Doing this in the context of web development is a lot easier, because we already have well known REST ( and most languages have libraries for making and parsing REST requests/responses ).

Also keep in mind that you need to implement some security features when doing this. For example when your Node.JS server is serving something only for your ASP.NET server you might want to restrict this Node.JS server, so it won't server this content to entire internet.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

Jon Galloway has [an article on this exact topic](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/10/26/using-node-js-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application-with-iisnode.aspx).